# Prestashop add a product timeout

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to add a product thanks to back office. However, when I go to add a product this appeared.

```
"A server error occurred while loading the tabs: some tabs could not be loaded.
Please try again by refreshing the page.
If you are still encountering this problem, please check your server logs or contact your hosting provider for assistance."
```

What's suprises me is that when **we look Network, scripts are canceled (not 500 error) after 30 seconds even if my max_execution_time is 60 seconds.**

[image]

Consequently, I search to my server logs and I found this but I not think it's related.

```
[Mon Aug 01 10:11:03.852933 2016] [:error] [pid 30238] [client 192.168.122.117:60428] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: nbItemsPerLine in /var/www/html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 49

[Mon Aug 01 10:11:03.852974 2016] [:error] [pid 30238] [client 192.168.122.117:60428] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 49

[Mon Aug 01 10:11:03.853026 2016] [:error] [pid 30238] [client 192.168.122.117:60428] PHP Warning:  math: function call nbItemsPerLine not allowed in /var/www/html/tools/smarty/plugins/function.math.php on line 53
[Mon Aug 01 10:11:03.853053 2016] [:error] [pid 30238] [client 192.168.122.117:60428] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: nbItemsPerLineTablet in /var/www/html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 51

[Mon Aug 01 10:11:03.853063 2016] [:error] [pid 30238] [client 192.168.122.117:60428] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 51
[Mon Aug 01 10:11:03.853085 2016] [:error] [pid 30238] [client 192.168.122.117:60428] PHP Warning:  math: function call nbItemsPerLineTablet not allowed in /var/www/html/tools/smarty/plugins/function.math.php on line 53
```

I'm a little bit lost do you know how do I solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure the max_execution_time is set to 60? In back office go to `Advanced Parameters` > `Configuration Information` and under `server information` the max execution time will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Does these warnings creating any actual issue (i.e. Cart problems etc.)?

If not, then simply turn off PrestaShop error reporting, these are just notices and can be ignored.

FYI, to enable disable debugging you can follow the steps below.

- open file: config/defines.inc.php (using FTP or hosting control panel)
- change true-->false:

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);